# ¿Cómo declaro una función con parámetro apuntador de una estructura no global en C?

Tags: c, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Quiero hacer una función en C que me llene una estructura , dicha estructura no es global.
La función la declaro previo a la función main como:

```
void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r);
```

Dentro de la función main la estructura se declara como:

```
struct colonias{ //Son 8 colonias máximo
    int cve;
    char nom[40];
}col[8];
```

Finalmente, después de la función main se describe la función alta2 como:

```
void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r){
int opc,i;
if(*r==8){
    printf("Ya hay 8 colonias dadas de alta...\n");
}
else{
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\tColonia: %d\n",r+1);
        printf("Clave: %d\n",100+r+1);
        (*p).cve=100+r+1;
        printf("Ingrese el nombre de la colonia: ");
        gets((*p).nom);
        printf("\nSi desea agregar otra colonia, ingrese [1], de lo contrario [0]: ");
        do{
            validar(&opc);
            if(opc<0 || opc>1)
                printf("Ingrese [1] o [0]: ");
        }while(opc<0 || opc>1);
        *r++;
        p++;
    }while(opc==1 || *r<8);
    if(*r==8){
        system("cls");
        printf("Ya hay 8 colonias dadas de alta, no se pueden agregar más...");
    }
}
*q=1;
```

}

Pero me arroja el error:

> error: conflicting types for 'alta2'

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Las estructuras no van adentro de funciones, sino, al principio del archivo. La pregunta es, ¿por qué lo pusiste adentro de la función? Si lo haces, no podrás usar los campos de la estructura en otras funciones, por más que declaras la estructura al principio, arrojará error y ojo, declarar una estructura no es lo mismo que definir. En tu ejemplo no estás declarando la estructura, sino, definiendo la estructura.

Comment: ¿Entonces puedo declarar y definir la estructura en la cabecera del programa? ¿Eso no cuenta como declarar una estructura de forma global? :(  Es que me pidieron que mi programa no tuviera variables globales y, a lo que entiendo, si una estructura esta en la cabecera del programa cuenta como global

Comment: Definir una variable global no es lo mismo que definir una estructura con ámbito global. Porque las estructuras en C no son variables, simplemente indica los miembros o campos que tendrá la estructura..

Comment: Muchísimas gracias entonces :)), con eso ya puedo hacer el programa ;)

Comment: De nada, de igual manera dejé una respuesta para responder a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

*Declarar* una estructura significa que solo podrás usar el tipo que creaste pero no sus campos (*o miembros*).

*Definir* una estructura significa que vamos a especificar los tipo de dato de cada miembro (con su respectivo nombre) de la estructura y por ende, podremos usarlo.

**Ejemplo del error:**

```c
void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r);

int main(void)
{   
    struct colonias
    { 
        int cve;
        char nom[40];
    }col[8];

    return 0;   
}

void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r)
{
    //more code...
}
```

El tipo `struct colonias` lo estamos usando en el prototipo y en la definición de la función `alta2`, sin embargo, el compilador dará error porque no reconoce el tipo y esto se debe porque no lo hemos declarado o definido para que el compilador sepa que existe dicho tipo.

Si en este caso declaramos la estructura, no daría error de compilación:

```c
//Declaramos la estructura
struct colonias;

void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r);

int main(void)
{   
    struct colonias
    { 
        int cve;
        char nom[40];
    }col[8];

    return 0;   
}

void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r)
{
    //more code...
}
```

Ahora sí podremos usar el tipo `struct colonias`, porque el compilador ya sabe que el tipo existe.

Sin embargo, si quisiera usar los campos de la estructura `colonias` de este modo:

```c
void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r)
{
    p->cve = 10; //error.
    //more code...
}
```

Nos dará otro error y esto se debe porque la definición de la estructura está en la función `main`, por lo tanto, solo podremos usar esos campos adentro del `main`, **porque ahí fue donde definiste la estructura con ámbito local**.

Lo que debes hacer es definir la estructura con **ámbito global** y de este modo podrás usar los campos en cualquier función.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
//Definimos la estructura con ámbito global.
struct colonias
{ 
    int cve;
    char nom[40];
}col[8];

void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r);

int main(void)
{   


    return 0;   
}

void alta2(struct colonias *p, int *q, int *r)
{
    p->cve = 10; // sin error.
    //more code...
}
```